# How to fix 'moving' Titlebar buttons in Global Menu (Manjaro Gnome)?

Tags: gnome, manjaro

Recently installed Manjaro Gnome and I'm quite happy with it overall. However, I think there's a bug of some kind when windows are Maximized, where the Titlebar buttons (minimize, unmaximize, and close window) are placed in the global menu (to save space, makes sense):

[image: note Titlebar buttons to the right of Dropbox icon]

The issue is that when I click the Dropbox icon, the Titlebar buttons disappear (presumably because a new app has focus), moving the Dropbox icon 3 'units' to the right:

[image: Default]
[image: After clicking Dropbox icon]

(Without right-aligned pictures, it's harder to see the annoying UX, whereby the icon I just clicked just moved a bunch of pixels to the right.)

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some kind of Gnome extension problem (or maybe setting). I think there is not much you can do, until developers fix or implement this. Check, if there is not some option for this in the extension settings. You can temporarily disable it if you can't outstand it.

Make sure you have installed the latest versions of your extensions. https://extensions.gnome.org/local/